# Barcode Scanner control barcodes - what type are they?

Tags: php, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am developing an application which utilizes a barcode scanner.  As you probably know, most barcode scanners have configuration options which are set by scanning special barcodes in the user manual.

To make the end user's life easier, I am incorporating the control barcodes into the application.  User can select which control command to execute, and the requisite barcode appears on the screen, eliminating the need to keep track of a paper manual, or dig for a PDF file.

The problem is that these on-screen barcodes are interpreted as data input, NOT as control commands.  I am generating them on-the-fly using the [Piqer BarcodeGenerator library](https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator) in PHP, however, using other libraries yields the same results.

When I scan the control codes with a barcode app on my phone, it reports they are of type CODE_128 and the values are 4-character commands, such as SX13 ("Enter Inventory Mode").

So I generated a CODE_128 barcode with the value "SX13" for the on-screen control code.  However, the reader simply interprets this as data entry, and types "SX13" into the data entry textbox on the app.

Upon comparison, I can see differences between the barcodes in the user manual and those generated in CODE_128 format.

Here's an example of the differences:
[image: Comparison of control code and generated codes]

What is the actual format/type of these command codes, if it's not CODE_128? Or has the manufacturer somehow tweaked/broken the CODE_128 specifications to prevent standard codes being interpreted as command sequences?

I really wanted to generate these dynamically instead of having to scan the images and display them as pictures.  Plus I'm interested in how this works.

Any info would be appreciated!

UPDATE: https://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/ reports that the value of the first barcode is prefixed with {FNC3}.  I assume this is a control character? How can I generate this?

Value of control code: {FNC3}SX13
Value of standard CODE_128 code: SX13

UPDATE 2: Per http://www.adams1.com/128table.html I see there is a FNC3 control code character (position 96 in the code128 table), represented by ASCII 128 character (Ç).  However, even this does not generate the correct sequence, as evidenced below:

[image: {FNC3}SX13 value]

Still not sure what I'm doing wrong...?